# How to select column in table by creating row in another table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables.

- tax_master
- item_master
- item_tax

The values in it are like this.

```
*tax_master*
tax_id  tax_name tax_value
--------------------------
  1     Vat      5
  2     LBT      8

*item_master*
item_id   Prise
---------------
  1        30
  2        100

*item_tax*
item_tax_id   item_id   tax_id
------------------------------
    1           1         1
    2           2         2
    3           1         2
```

Now i want output like this.

```
item_id  prise VAT   LBT   Total_prise
---------------------------------------
   1      30   1.5   2.4      33.9
   2     100    -     8       108
```

VAT value is calculated like `5/30*100` like `5%` on `30=1.5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select item_id, price,
       (min(case when tax_name = 'VAT' then tax end)) vat,
       (min(case when tax_name = 'LBT' then tax end)) lbt,
       coalesce(min(case when tax_name = 'VAT' then tax end),0) +
       coalesce(min(case when tax_name = 'LBT' then tax end),0) +
       price total
  from 
      (select a.item_id item_id,
              c.tax_name tax_name,
              (c.tax_value * b.price / 100) tax,
              b.price price
         from item_tax a inner join item_master b on a.item_id = b.item_id
                         inner join tax_master c on a.tax_id = c.tax_id) as calc
 group by item_id, price;
```

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6e45/4).

Comment: But it gives me an error like "Every table must have its own alias"... What i have to do????

Comment: AND again i have one problem that now i want to add price+VAT+LBT for particular item as total price... Can you please help me...

Comment: Thanks a lot it works vary well... Thats what i was searching for... You are genius...

Comment: Since you are using inner joins: if neither VAT nor LBT is linked to an item you won't get a record. [Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77f9d/2)

Answer (score 0):

The following statement should return the data the way you want it:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    item_master.item_id,
   (SELECT
        tax_master.tax_value * item_master.prise / 100
    FROM
        item_tax, tax_master
    WHERE
        item_tax.item_id = item_master.item_id and
        tax_master.tax_id = item_tax.tax_id and
        tax_master.tax_name = 'VAT') as VAT,

   (SELECT
        tax_master.tax_value * item_master.prise / 100
    FROM
        item_tax, tax_master
    WHERE
        item_tax.item_id = item_master.item_id and
        tax_master.tax_id = item_tax.tax_id and
        tax_master.tax_name = 'LBT') as LBT
FROM
    item_tax, item_master, tax_master    
WHERE
    item_master.item_id = item_tax.item_id and
    tax_master.tax_id = item_tax.tax_id
```

bwt: I think **prise** should be meant to be **price** ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot it works... I am very happy... And yes that will be price

Comment: But again i have one problem that now i want to add price+VAT+LBT for particular item as total price... Can you please help me...

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: I tried it out with a fiddle and you need a MAX (or MIN) to group them) on top of the left joins:

```
SELECT item_master.item_id,
       MAX(item_master.price * tax_master_vat.tax_value / 100) as VAT,
       MAX(item_master.price * tax_master_lbt.tax_value / 100) as LBT
FROM item_master
LEFT JOIN item_tax ON item_master.item_id = item_tax.item_id
LEFT JOIN tax_master tax_master_vat ON item_tax.tax_id = tax_master_vat.tax_id
                                   AND tax_master_vat.tax_name = 'VAT'
LEFT JOIN tax_master tax_master_lbt ON item_tax.tax_id = tax_master_lbt.tax_id
                                   AND tax_master_lbt.tax_name = 'LBT'
GROUP BY item_master.item_id
```

If there's no tax_value linked for a certain item, it should return NULL (multiplying with NULL is NULL). If you want to show something different from 'null' (or nothing) you can use COALESCE. If you want to include the total price:

If you want to add the price or the total you can left join this on the item_master table:

```
SELECT item_master.item_id,
       tax.VAT,
       tax.LBT,
       item_master.price + COALESCE(tax.VAT, 0) + COALESCE(tax.LBT, 0) AS Total
FROM item_master
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT item_master.item_id,
                   MAX(item_master.price * tax_master_vat.tax_value / 100) as VAT,
                   MAX(item_master.price * tax_master_lbt.tax_value / 100) as LBT
                   FROM item_master
            LEFT JOIN item_tax ON item_master.item_id = item_tax.item_id
            LEFT JOIN tax_master tax_master_vat ON item_tax.tax_id = tax_master_vat.tax_id
                                               AND tax_master_vat.tax_name = 'VAT'
            LEFT JOIN tax_master tax_master_lbt ON item_tax.tax_id = tax_master_lbt.tax_id
                                               AND tax_master_lbt.tax_name = 'LBT'
            GROUP BY item_master.item_id ) tax ON item_master.item_id = tax.item_id
```

Or, you can use the OVER PARTITION BY clause (lets you group on item_id only but still include the price field):

```
SELECT item_id,
       price,
       VAT,
       LBT,
       price + COALESCE(VAT, 0) + COALESCE(LBT, 0) AS Total
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT
              item_master.item_id,
              item_master.price,
              MAX(item_master.price * tax_master_vat.tax_value / 100) OVER (PARTITION BY item_master.item_id) as VAT,
              MAX(item_master.price * tax_master_lbt.tax_value / 100) OVER (PARTITION BY item_master.item_id) as LBT
       FROM item_master
       LEFT JOIN item_tax ON item_master.item_id = item_tax.item_id
       LEFT JOIN tax_master tax_master_vat ON item_tax.tax_id = tax_master_vat.tax_id
                                          AND tax_master_vat.tax_name = 'VAT'
       LEFT JOIN tax_master tax_master_lbt ON item_tax.tax_id = tax_master_lbt.tax_id
                                          AND tax_master_lbt.tax_name = 'LBT'
    ) price_and_tax
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d3076/14)

Comment: How you take tax_master_vat.tax_value... although vat is a field under tax_name

Comment: And again i have one problem that now i want to add price+VAT+LBT for particular item as total price... Can you please help me...

Comment: @SwapnilGanjegaonkar Some updates. Second example is very similar to Ramblin' Man's answer (using left joins instead of CASE). You might want to try out what happens if neither VAT nor LBT are defined.