# how to select row values as columns of another table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have three tables as

1) tax_master

```
-------------------------------
|  tax_id ||tax_name||tax_value|
--------------------------------
|   1     ||    VAT ||   5     |
--------------------------------
|   2     ||    LBT ||   8     |
-------------------------------
```

2) item_master

```
----------------------
|  item_id ||price   |
----------------------
|   1     ||   30    |
----------------------
|   2     ||   100   |
----------------------
```

3) item_tax

```
-----------------------------------
|  item_tax_id ||item_tax||item_id|
-----------------------------------
|   1          ||  1     ||   1   |
-----------------------------------
|   2          ||    2   ||   2   |
-----------------------------------
|   2          ||    2   ||   1   |
-----------------------------------
```

so now i want output like that

```
----------------------------------
|  item_id ||  VAT   ||   LBT    |
----------------------------------
|   1      ||  1.5   ||   2.4    |
----------------------------------
|   2      ||   -    ||   1.6    |
----------------------------------
```

values of vat is calculated as like 5/100*30 as 5% on 30=1.5
So want output like that im very confused. and tried a lot but dint succeed.
Can you please help me out

Comment: It's called crosstab.  Search for it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18400249/how-to-select-column-in-table-by-creating-row-in-another-table-in-mysql

Comment: please don't cross post

Comment: Possibly it's too early but how are you getting 1.6 for item_id =2?